# Why is this activation function nonlinear in the parameters but linear in the variables?

Tags: machine-learning

I am taking a course on machine learning. My textbook says that a certain category of activation function of the following form, are linear in the variable vector x, but nonlinear in the parameters:

> y(x) = f(w^T x + w0)

Why is the function **nonlinear** in the parameters but **linear** in the variables, even though in the above equation we can just substitute the variables with the parameters without changing the functional form?

here is the relevant excerpt:

> f( · ) is known as an activation function. [...] The decision surfaces
>   correspond to y(x) = constant, so that wTx + w0 = constant and hence
>   the decision surfaces are linear functions of x, even if the function
>   f(·) is nonlinear. [...] Note, however, that in contrast to the models
>   used for regression, **they are no longer linear in the parameters due
>   to the presence of the nonlinear function f(·)**.

Comment: This might make sense if you specify a particular $f$. Just for the sake of argument, suppose that $f(x)=\cos(w^Tx+w_0)$. What do you notice happens when you fix $w$ and $x$ but vary $w_0$ between $-2\pi$ and $2\pi$?

Comment: "The decision surfaces
correspond to y(x) = constant, so that wTx + w0 = constant and hence the decision
surfaces are linear functions of x, even if the function f(·) is nonlinear"
why y(x) = constant, isn't y(x) changes as x changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call $r:=r(x)=w^Tx+w_0$ the *response*. The response is a number, and as a function of response the activation is $f(r)$. This function is nonlinear in $r$. On the other hand, the response $r(x)$ is linear in $x$: $r(ax+by)=ar(x)+br(y)$ for constants $a,b$ and vectors $x,y$.

Your features $x$ combine with the weight $w$ to form a response $r$. In this way, many different kinds of $x$ will give you a similar response $r$. For example if $w=(1,1)$ and $w_0=0$, then $x=(1,2)$ and $x=(4,-1)$ will give you the same response $r=3$. To the activation function, data points which yield similar responses are indistinguishable and hence will yield similar activations. However the activation is nonlinear in $r$ so that if $x$ yields response $r(x)$ and $y$ yields response $r(y)$, then $f(r(x)+r(y))$ does not necessarily equal $f(r(x))+f(r(y))$. Thinking of $f$ as a function of $x,y$:

$$f(r(x+y))=f(r(x)+r(y))\neq f(r(x))+f(r(y)).$$